# How to fix address bar not displaying after fullScreenExit

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to display address bar immediately after exiting fullscreen but nothing seems to work.
I saw different method, both JavaScript and CSS but the address bar still hides after I exit fullscreen, the only way it shows back is if I scroll up.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

Is not working for JS and CSS below is not working either.

```
body {
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: put your code HTML, CSS, and JS in a snippet. window.scroll needs a condition to work. did you put it in an if statement or not? and what is the relationship between scroll and full screen?